# How to align text in button of table in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use "Bootstrap-4". Imagine I have the following table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">  
    <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item 01</th>
                <th>Item 02</th>
                <th class="col">Buttons</th>
                <th class="col-1">Item 04</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Item 01</td>
                <td>Very length column</td>
                <th class="col">
                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
                                -
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col text-center quantity">
                            7 in cart
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                          <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
                              +
                          </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th class="col-1">Item 04</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The button signs such as `-` and `+` looks great at big screens:

[image]

However, at smaller devices(e.g.,`275px`) these signs are not aligned:

[image]

Is it possibe to align signs such as `-` and `+` in buttons at smaller devices?

[An example can be seen here.](https://www.codeply.com/p/YlTEk4SEdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep them aligned, remove the [`btn-block`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/buttons/#sizes) class from each `<button>` element. This will remove the `width: 100%` and prevent them from resizing at smaller viewport widths:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item 01</th>
        <th>Item 02</th>
        <th class="col">Buttons</th>
        <th class="col-1">Item 04</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 01</td>
        <td>Very length column</td>
        <th class="col">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-2">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center quantity">
              7 in cart
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th class="col-1">Item 04</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```